# multi function socket java, socket vs NIO socket

Tags: java, sockets

Take it easy with me, I'm new in socket programming.

I'm about making a program which is similar to Teamviewer. I could make a simple Server/client application which is multithreaded. But the problem is I couldn't figure out how to do something like :
Let's say I have Server and a client connected to server.
I could transfer a file from client to server. I could make a simple chat with a client. But my problem is : How can I chat with the client while file is transferring in the same time? I mean I couldn't make more than one function in a time.Because we have just one input and one output for both server and client. So how could I send more that one function to client and how could the client read more that one function in a time and respond to requests ?
I did something like : I sent a request to client and I got the response in a new thread which contains a new DataInputStream but I couldn't figure out how the main DataInputStream will receive a new response from the client because what is receiving the requests in this way is the new DataInputStream. I'm really lost in this situation because I feel my concept is completely wrong but I couldn't figure out the right concept to do something like that.
Is it possible with ServerSocket or should I look at NIO Socket ?

**NOTE :**
I don't want a piece of code, I would like to understand the concept of the whole operation for something like that. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *packet* based massaging system over a single connection

Outgoing

```
{"type":"chat", "message":"hi"}
{"type":"xfer", "fileName":"fileX", "data":"some_binary_data"}
```

Incoming

```
switch(getString("type")){

    case "chat":
        System.out.println("User said" + getString("message"));
        break;

    case "xfer":
        File f = new File(getString("fileName"));
        f.write(getString("data"));
        break;

    ...
}
```

Obviously if the binary file is fairly large, you should break it into many different messages and reassemble it on the other side, this would allow chat messages to make their way across the wire while the transfer is also still taking place.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.  The first one is actually need more than port I think and I don't prefer to use it.
The second one, I tried it but here is the problem. When I start like an example screen sharing, it works fine, but if I want to send another funcion :  I got a respnd but then I'm facing 
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
which means the data couldn't arrive at all. And that's where I started to get lost. As I think because I'm using oneinput and output. But I don't really knew what is goind on ! Even If I added them to threads , got the same results

Comment: This now gets into a very specific and complex issue that without code is impossible to do anything about. You will need to properly manage all messages and threads that are using the socket. All I gave was simple theory on how it can be done, the pseudo code alone is not thread safe.

Comment: I'm great about what u just said, I wanted to be sure that I'm in the right direction before moving on. If the solution u  said could work, I'll start to write some codes here to figure out the problem. Can I edit this question to add server/client code ? I'm sorry I'm new here and sorry for my bad English.